# Language in unused reputation recalc page is slightly offensive

Tags: feature-request, reputation-recalc

At https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, an emphasis hurt me. Deeply.

> days represented 682
>   rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 92 days

I know that I have only reached the rep cap on 92 days; there’s no need to rub it in with asterisks, of all things!

I propose a wording change:

> days represented 682
>   rep cap was reached via rep from *upvotes alone* on 92 days

If this is implemented, I’m sure that the world will be all the happier for it.

Comment: Ha ha look at this guy he has *only* 18 Meta reputation

Comment: That page is going away anyway I thought, as recalcs are not needed anymore. I suspect that SE hiding the page is more likely than SE adjusting the formatting of that sentence.

Comment: Or `from *upvotes only*`. Just move one asterisk to make it unoffensive.

Comment: Gramatically speaking, it can be read in two different ways: "rep cap was reached via rep [from upvotes *only*] on 92 days" or "rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes [*only* on 92 days]" - Depending on which way you read it, it may or may not be "offensive".

Comment: I can't tell if this is a serious question or an attempt at an April Fools joke. It looks kinda serious and the user is apparently new to the wild wooly world of Meta, but then again it contains a *signature*.

Comment: @CodyGray he's not new, look at his history.

Comment: Deeply! Seriously?

Comment: I doubt this will ever get changed. The reputation page is not exactly a priority, and that line is completely inaccurate to begin with.